# Pointer to a function that takes a pointer to another function as argument

Tags: c, function, pointers, functor

This should be a simple question, but I might not be able to word it correctly or I might be trying to defy the principles of the C language because of my lack of experience with it.

All I want to do is, given a pointer to a function, to wrap it inside another function that takes a pointer to a function as an argument, and make a pointer of the later. Better in code:

```
void do_nothing_1() {}
void do_nothing_2() {}

void wrapper(void(*f)()) { f(); }

int main() {

    // the following will call the function
    // but i just want a pointer of whats being called
    funcion_pointer_1 = wrapper(do_nothing_1);
    funcion_pointer_2 = wrapper(do_nothing_2);

    return 0;
}
```

I apologize beforehand if the question doesn't make any sense, please help me clarify it rather than simply downvote it.

Edit: Given the apparent difficulty to obtain the results desired because of the obscurity of the requirements, I will be a little more specific on what I am looking for.

Inside a struct, I have a pointer to a function:

```
struct my_struct {
    int (* run)(void);
}
```

What I want to do is to modify that function and that's why I use the wrapper. So, for example, if foo returns void change that to int. Also, run some code before executing foo:

```
int wrapper(void (*foo)()) {

    // exec some stuff here

    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Ultimately, what I want is that when I execute the function corresponding to the *run pointer from my structure, execute some stuff before doing run() and change the return type.

Comment: Do you want a _function pointer_ to `wrapper`?

Comment: more precisely to wrapper(foo)

Comment: Can you change your code so there are not so many `foo`s -- shadowing will complicate things.

Comment: `wrapper(foo)` is not a function, so you can't get a _function pointer_ to it.

Comment: Are you looking for [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)?  If so, consider something such as [libffcall](http://www.gnu.org/software/libffcall/).

Comment: is it just a function caller then? would I need to implement a struct to achieve what I'm looking for or is it plain impossible?

Comment: A function pointer doesn't hold information about the function parameters, if that's what you're trying to do.  It's just the address of a function.

Answer (score 3):

When struggling with the correct syntax, it is helpful to use typedefs to make things clearer.  Not just for yourself as you write the code, but for anyone who needs to maintain it, or just try to figure out what it's doing.

You want a function pointer to a function that takes another function pointer as an argument.  Start with the argument, a function without parameters and no return value:

```
typedef void (*void_handler_t)( void);
```

And now the wrapper function pointer, one that takes a function pointer parameter and has no return value:

```
typedef void (*wrapper_handler_t)( void_handler void_fn);
```

And the code:

```
void foo( void) {}
void wrapper( void_handler_t wrapped_fn)
{
    wrapped_fn();
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wrapper_handler_t function_pointer;

    function_pointer = &wrapper;
    function_pointer( &foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great tip about the syntax and the typedef, I will upvote just for that, thanks. I am uncertain if this is doing what I am looking for. Is there any way that I could do something like:

    function_pointer = &wrapper(&foo);
    function_pointer();

Comment: typedefs for anything other than opaque data lead only to homocide

Comment: @tbert what do you have against typedef? Is it considered bad practice?

Comment: @omtinez having to deconstruct code where all structs get called foo_t, which leads to not being able to use data structures outside of one file without having to sodomize your naming schemes, etc.; basically, the loss of clarity that comes along with their constant overuse

Comment: @tbert: I'm not sure I understand how `struct foo` is clearer than `foo_t`.  I don't like people who typedef pointers to other types, but I think it makes a lot of sense for function pointers, especially when you have those pointers as elements in other structs, or parameters to other functions.

Comment: @tomlogic how is "foo_t" clearer than "struct foo"? I know what I can do with a struct, because I know what it is and that it's intended to be poked; I see "foo_t" and don't know if it's a struct, an int, a char, or some strange new datatype the world has heretofore not been privy to. To my mind (and, frankly, I'm going to go all "if you do this you're wrong"), having a "foo_t" datatype indicates that there are no user-serviceable parts inside.